# jReject: jQuery Browser Rejection - Images are not being loaded

Tags: jquery, image

I'm having a problem loading images in the script

The images are inside the folder: Content / images

But when entering the path, they are not found.

I have tried the following ways:

```
imagePath: '~/Content/images /',
imagePath: '.Content/images /',
```

This is the path that the browser is returning as not found:

```
http: //localhost:7539/Account/~/Content/images/ browser_chrome.gif
```

This script is called inside the Account page, but how do I remove the "account" from the path to be able to locate the images?

Comment: Likely `"images/"` and no space I assume the page is ALSO in Content

Comment: still haven't found the images http://localhost:7539/Account/images/browser_chrome.gif 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Look in the network tab to see where the page is loaded from. Is this React or something? Can you show a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan No, it's just a jquey script that im using inside a asp.net mvc project, which detects which browser the user is using. The images are not in the same folder on the page, but wouldn't it be possible to use them without being on the same page? http://jreject.turnwheel.com/

Comment: Depends on the server